# MVC paradigm. Why only application_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Rails uses the MVC paradigm. It's interesting in models, views, and controllers, really only controllers have an 'application' or parent controller. Actually there is an application_helper in rails but it really doesn't do much. What's the point of only have an application_controller where as models and in practice helpers do not have a parent?

Comment: interesting debate launched, +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Models have a parent, ActiveRecord::Base
ApplicationController is there because its too common to see application wide filters that you need in a web app for authentication/authorization etc. The application helper, again is there to put helper methods that get used across the application, beyond the scope of just one controller.

Comment: I thought Active::Record is more of a mixin than a parent although it does inherit from it.

Answer (score 3):

Models are the cohesive and supposed to be the most independent entities in the MVC framework. In this context, it is not good comparing Model vs Controller.

Helpers are something that supports the view. For example, you may end up writing some actual piece of rails code inside a view which may be reusable across different views. For those scenarios, helpers will come to the rescue.

And Controllers are the ones that has to ideally speak between a view and the underlying models. It is logical to have a parent of all controllers, the application controller to do this.

And all classes in Rails MVC framework have a parent - ActiveRecord::Base is the parent for models, ActionController::Base is the parent for Controllers. Since helpers are for views, they don't have a parent at least explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking generally of MVC rather than specifically about rails:

The generic controller is beneficial, as stated, for generic handling common to all controllers, it executes before the specific controller. The same applies to models, in that there may be some generic properties which the model can benefit from. This can generally be better accomplished by inheritance, where your model inherits an "application model".

This is why you ofter see generic controllers, but not models. There is already a means of getting generic behavior in models, but that is not the case with contollers.